# How to bound the maximal consecutive length in a random subset of [n] as function of n?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, limits, functions

Let $S$ be a random subset of $[n]=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ chosen uniformly from $[n]$'s subsets. How can I find a function $f(n)$ s.t. for any $\varepsilon \gt 0$,

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} P\left[(1- \varepsilon) f(n) \le \lambda (S) \le (1 + \varepsilon)f(n)\right]=1 ?$$

Comment: What is the purpose of these 2 links?

Comment: What did you try to solve this question?

Comment: @Did related material I found but didn't help me. may helps to other people.

Comment: What did you try to solve this question?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the answer: $f(n)=\log_2n$. I hesitate to post a full proof, for the usual reasons.

Comment: I didn't find How can I bound it using one of this equlities: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_inequalities, tried Chernoff's inequality, and Markov's

Comment: http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~larry/=stat705/Lecture2.pdf

Comment: Concerning the usual reasons: On MathOverflow, we're getting flags claiming that this user's questions come from a take-home exam that is in progress.

Comment: @ScottCarnahan Thanks for the information. This is not what I was referring to but confirms my hesitations.

Comment: And now the OP is seemingly [covering their tracks](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/300964).